# How do I make the textbox close to the text label

Tags: html, css

I'm using the theme Pixeladmin (http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB07403R9)

As you might see here in this picture:
[image: My image]

My textbox is far away from my label and I want it to be closer so I wonder how do I do this?

Here's my code for the box:

```
<div class="row form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Author:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" name="author" id="author" placeholder="Author Name" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Note you can view the css source on the preview site,
I appreciate all the help.

Comment: where are those text buttons?

Comment: Dont use the grid for this case. Give your label a fixed width, e.g 200px and the textarea a width of calc(100% -200px) then let both elements float left.

Comment: give a jsfiddle example

Comment: @mimo how would I do that? I don't have much experience in html/css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example with a new css3 feature: the calc method.

The advantage is the absolute width of the label. The input will take the rest of the given space.
html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label pull-left">Author:</label>
    <input type="text" name="author" id="author" placeholder="Author Name" class="form-control pull-left">
</div>
```

css:

```
label {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 7px;
}

#author {
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qakxpe35/

Answer (score 0):

since you are using bootstrap columns and probably want to keep the columns in tact, i would suggest 1 of 2 ways: make the left col width 1 or text align the left columns text to the right like below.

if you dont want to use columns for this you can do the following

```
.labelLeft {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 65px;
    float:left;
}
.divLeft {
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    width: calc(100% - 65px);
}

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label labelLeft">Author:</label>
    <div class="divLeft">
        <input type="text" name="author" id="author" placeholder="Author Name" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.labelLeft {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 65px;
    float:left;
}
.divLeft {
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    width: calc(100% - 65px);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row form-group"> <!-- original -->
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Author:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="author" id="author" placeholder="Author Name" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<div class="row form-group"> <!-- bootstrap column size 1 -->
    <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Author:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-11">
        <input type="text" name="author" id="author" placeholder="Author Name" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="row form-group"> <!-- aligning text to the right -->
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label text-right">Author:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="author" id="author" placeholder="Author Name" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<div class="form-group"> <!-- not using bootstrap grid, fixing width of the label -->
    <label class="control-label labelLeft">Author:</label>
    <div class="divLeft">
        <input type="text" name="author" id="author" placeholder="Author Name" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how would I change the width of the left col? I don't have much experience with css/html.

Comment: the width of the columns in bootstrap are denoted by `col-sm-#`, the smaller the number, the smaller the width (by percentage in relation with the screen)

Comment: @induitablee I made a a copy of the col-sm2 and changed it to col-sm22 then I changed the width on it to 1% but now my textbox is on the left instead of the right as you see: http://prntscr.com/83dvgz 
my code: http://prntscr.com/83dw29
my bootstrap.min css: http://prntscr.com/83dwcd

Comment: thats because the syntax isnt `col-sm2` its `col-sm-2`. and its col sizes are based out of a full row of 12 columns. please read the bootstrap documentation on the grid system found here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid